# How to write the formula in Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Formula is:

$$\emptyset=((p \lor r)\to q)\land (q\to r)$$
This is what I've already done:

$$(p \lor r) \lor \lnot q)\land (q \lor \lnot r)$$
$$(p \lor r \lor \lnot q)\land (q \lor \lnot r)$$

and then, I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Hint;

$p\rightarrow q \equiv \neg\;p\vee q$

Hence

$(p\vee r)\rightarrow q\equiv \neg(p\vee r) \vee q \equiv (\neg p\wedge \neg r)\vee q$